# react-mde can't install on "react": "^18.2.0"

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error from the terminal while installing `react-mde` npm package:

```
  npm i react-mde
```

Above command gives error below:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: notesapp@0.1.0     
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:       
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from react-mde@11.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-mde
npm ERR!   react-mde@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Peter.Njuguna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
``
```

Comment: It doesn't support React 18 yet

Comment: might be version conflict, please try with `--legacy-peer-deps` flag, Run `npm i react-mde --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 5):

try this **`npm i react-mde --legacy-peer-deps`**

[Check this documentation](https://www.querythreads.com/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-what-s-a-potential-use-case/)

Answer (score 1):

`react-mde` does not support react 18 yet. To to use `react-mde` in react 18 use below command.

```
npm i react-mde --legacy-peer-deps
```

To use `react-mde` with its properties and its css styling import following:

```
import ReactMde from "react-mde";
import 'react-mde/lib/styles/css/react-mde-all.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue and i tried this command:
npm i react-mde --force,
but mde didn't work properly like the icons are not showing up

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in the given output i.e: all you need is to add

```
--legacy-peer-deps
```